# How do I take the values ​of the Price Range Slider and write them in php variables?

Tags: javascript, sql

How can I take the values: minimum cost (selected) and maximum cost (selected) and write them in the variables: $ MaxPrice and $ MinPrice?

The code I use:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrXzbX

I tried to take the values ​​by adding a span name (irs-to and irs-from).

```
'<span name="MinPrice" class="irs-from">0</span><span name="MaxPrice" class="irs-to">0</span><span class="irs-single">0</span>' +
```

Comment: You need to make form with inputs and submit button and then you can collect them with `$_POST`

Comment: I create this form and i use $_GET

Comment: You can use `$_GET` also but then your users will see values in your link